# Tela de perfil de contato material and design

Tags: android, material-design

Opa.

Alguem sabe se tem algum projeto pronto no github ou em outro lugar deste tipo de tela ? É a tela de contatos com material and design

[image: Tela login material and design]

Gostaria de implementar esta tela no meu projeto.

Obrigado.

Comment: no android studio tem a Scrolling Activity que é beeem similar. Click direito no pacote > New > Activity > Gallery > Scrolling Activity.